# Filter array by first letter

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

I'm building a platform. Somewhere in my code, there's an array that looks like this (PHP):

```
$entries = array('p01','p02','g01','g02','a001','a002')
```

I need to write a script that filters the array based on the first letter. For example, asking for those with the starting letter "p" would give me

```
$filtered_entries = array('p01','p02');
```

Similarly, if I asked for those with starting letter "g" or "a" it would give me those as well. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: [Native function to filter array by prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2405785/2943403)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an `array_filter()` function in PHP which you can use to accomplish this:

`$filtered = array_filter($array, create_function('$a', 'return $a[0] == "' . $letter . '";'));`

<strike>I'll leave it to you to generalize the function to handle all the letters.</strike>

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Technically valid, but creating all the functions for all the different characters may become somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: I spoke of generalization to hint that there's a simple way to do it for all the letters Brandon Wang might need that does not consist of copying, pasting and changing one character in the code.

Comment: Better use `var_export` than simple string concatenation.

Comment: Ah, the old `create_function`, always smelled a lot like `eval` to me, I seriously had almost forgotten about it since closures. This is a valid working example indeed.

Comment: @jmz thanks for your help! I'm a bit confused on how exactly I'm supposed to generalize this code :( Can you help out?

Comment: This works! I haven't figured out how to generalize but for now it works. Thanks everyone!

Comment: OK, I can generalize by throwing it into a function.

Comment: actually, my answer is way better ))

Answer (score 1):

```
class FirstCharFilter {
    public $char = 'p';
    function filter(array $array){
        return array_filter($array,array($this,'checkFirstChar'));
    }
    public function checkFirstChar($a){
       return $a[0] == $this->char;
    }
}
$filter = new FirstCharFilter();
$filter->char = 'p';
var_dump($filter->filter($array));
$filter->char = 'g';
var_dump($filter->filter($array));
```

Or if you only need to loop, extend `FilterIterator`:

```
class FirstCharIterator extends FilterIterator {
    public $char = '';
    function accept(){
        $string = $this->current();
        return is_string($string) && $string[0] == $this->char;
    }
}
$iter = new FirstCharIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
$iter->char = 'p';
foreach($iter as $item) echo $item."\n";
```

Comment: Like the use of the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

```
$entries = array('p01','p02','g01','g02','a001','a002');
print_r(
    preg_grep('~^p~', $entries) // or preg_grep("~^$letter~",.....
);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter_array($array, $letter){
$filtered_array=array();
 foreach($array as $key=>$val){
  if($val[0]==$letter){
   $filtered_array[]=$val;
  }
 }
return $filtered_array;
}
```

use it like this to get all p's

```
$entries = array('p01','p02','g01','g02','a001','a002')
$filtered=filter_array($entries, 'p');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$entries = array('p01','p02','g01','g02','a001','a002');

$filterVar = null;

function filterFunction($v) {
    global $filterVar;

    if (substr($v,0,1) == $filterVar) {
        return $v;
    }
}

$filterVar = 'a';
$newEntries = array_filter($entries,'filterFunction');


var_dump($newEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of generating filter functions using a closure.

```
function filter_factory($letter) {
    return function ($input) use ($letter) {
        return is_string($input) && $input[0] === $letter;
    };
}

$entries   = array('p01','p02','g01','g02','a001','a002');
$p_entries = array_filter($entries, filter_factory('p'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of **solution** is much more **intuitive** and **dynamic**.
In this example, there are several types of solutions:

- Search in the **first letters**
- **Sensitive** to capital letters
- is_array() so if it tends to avoid several **errors**

---

```
<?php

/*
 * Search within an asociative array
 * Examples:
 * $array = array('1_p01','1_P02','2_g01','2_g02','3_a001','3_a002');
 * find_in_array($array,'2');
 * return:  array( 2 => '2_g01',3 => '2_g02')
 *
 * find_in_array($array,'2',false);
 * return:  array( 1 => '1_P02')
 *
 * find_in_array($array,'P0',false,false);
 * return: array( 0 => '1_p01',1 => '1_P02')
 *
 */

function find_in_array($array, $find='', $FirstChar=true, $CaseInsensitive=true){
    if ( is_array($array) ){
        return preg_grep("/".($FirstChar ? '^':'')."{$find}/".($CaseInsensitive ? '':'i'), $array);
    }
}

$array = array('1_p01','1_P02','2_g01','2_g02','3_a001','3_a002');

$a = find_in_array($array,'2');
var_export($a);
/*
Return: 
array (
  2 => '2_g01',
  3 => '2_g02'
)
*/

$a = find_in_array($array,'P0',false);
var_export($a);
/*
Return: 
array (
  1 => '1_P02'
)
*/

$a = find_in_array($array,'P0',false,false);
var_export($a);
/*
Return: 
array (
  0 => '1_p01',
  1 => '1_P02'
)
*/
```