# How to search an array for matching text

Tags: php, arrays

was wondering if there's a function to search an array, where the first letter matches a letter chosen.  I could do something less elegant like

```
Loop through array 
Each item remove the first character, match to chosen search variable   e.g if the first letter from apple, a equals my selection a, show.
```

Comment: Could you post what you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter array by first letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366456/filter-array-by-first-letter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But below I give you an example of selecting only the selected elements of an array that contain the first letter you want:

```
function select_from_array($first_letter,$array){
    $return = Array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
        if($array[$i][0] === $first_letter) $return[] = $array[$i];
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Example:

```
$arr = Array("Nice","Chops","Plot","Club");
print_r(select_from_array('C',$arr));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Chops
    [1] => Club
)
```

Comment: you can use this function for other uses by simply changing the `if` condition.